# Distribute functions to multiple tasks

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I want to distribute subroutines to different tasks with OpenMP.
In my code I implemented this:

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp single
   do thread = 1, omp_get_num_threads()
       !$omp task
            write(*,*) "Task,", thread, "is computing"
            call find_pairs(me, thread, points)
            call count_neighbors(me, thread, neighbors(:, thread))
       !$omp end task
   end do
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel
```

The subroutines find_neighbors and count_neighbors do some calculations.
I set the number of threads in my program before with:

```
nr_threads = 4
call omp_set_num_threads(nr_threads)
```

Compiling this with GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0 and running,
gives me only one thread, running at nearly 100% when monitoring with top. Nevertheless, it prints the right

> Task,     1 is computing
>
> Task,     2 is computing
>
> Task,     3 is computing
>
> Task,     4 is computing

I compile it using:

```
gfortran -fopenmp main.f90 -o program
```

What I want is to distribute different calls of the subroutines according to
the number of OpenMP threads, working in parallel.

From what I understand is, that a single thread is created which creates the different
tasks.

Comment: just an idea: replace `omp_get_thread_num()` by `omp_get_num_threads()`...

Comment: was definitely not correct, but doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Did you check how many threads were created? Something like `print(omp_get_num_threads())` The problem may be elsewhere, you may only be getting one thread, for various reasons. Then there would be no other thread to execute the tasks.

Comment: Also check the obvious - what exactly is the compile line you are using? To what value is OMP_NUM_THREADS set?

Comment: I added more information to the original question.

Comment: What is printed if you print out the return value of omp_get_thread_num() within the task?

Comment: Use `write(*,*) "Task,", omp_get_thread_num(), "is computing"` to see whether the tasks are distributed across multiple threads. Also, add `print(omp_get_num_threads())` or similar in the parallel region before the loop starts. I am still not convinced that your code generates multiple threads to begin with.